# How to fetch a message by its ID then react to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the message ID of a newly created message like this.
What would I use instead of `message.channel.fetch(id)` to fetch a message id? I can't seem to find it:

```js
async function messageSend() {
  let messageId = await message.channel.send('Test');
  let { id } = messageId;
  const emojiCheck = '✅';
  const emojiNo = '❌';
  const nebzlaID = '569860318608490496';
  message.channel.messages.fetch(id).react(emojiCheck);
  message.channel.messages.fetch(id).react(emojiNo);

  const suggestionDM = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#fffff')
    .setTitle('There is a new suggestion in abc!').setDescription(`
        User: ${suggestUser}
        \n\nSuggestion: ${suggestion}

        `);
  // ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`channel.messages.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise, it means you need to resolve it first to get the message you can react to. You can use `await`:

```js
async function messageSend() {
  const { id } = await message.channel.send('Test');
  const emojiCheck = '✅';
  const emojiNo = '❌';
  const nebzlaID = '569860318608490496';

  const messageToReact = await message.channel.messages.fetch(id);

  messageToReact.react(emojiCheck);
  messageToReact.react(emojiNo);

  // ...
```

Although it's not necessary to fetch it again, you could simply react to the returned message:

```js
async function messageSend() {
  const sentMessage = await message.channel.send('Test');
  const emojiCheck = '✅';
  const emojiNo = '❌';
  const nebzlaID = '569860318608490496';

  sendMessage.react(emojiCheck);
  sendMessage.react(emojiNo);

  // ...
```